# Servlet session is not persistent

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies, curl

I have a servlet like the following

```
public class Ticket extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Ticket() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // check cookies
    Cookie[] receivedCookies = request.getCookies();
    if(receivedCookies != null){
        Cookie user = receivedCookies[0];

        response.getWriter().println("user: " + user.getValue());
        response.addCookie(user);

        // check session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        Object atribVal = session.getAttribute(user.getValue()); // get a current state

        if(atribVal == null){
            response.getWriter().println("current state: null");
        }
        else{
            response.getWriter().println("current state: " + atribVal.toString());
        }           

        String newState = TicketMachine.getNextState(atribVal); // get a new state based on the current one

        response.getWriter().println("new state: " + newState);

        if(newState == "COMPLETED"){ // ticket completed, destroy session
             session.invalidate();
             return;
        }
        else{ // move to the next state
            session.setAttribute(user.getValue(), newState);                
        }           
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to store a state of a ticket machine for each user who requests a ticket. I'm running this on Oracle WebLogic Server and testing it using cURL get requests that looks like the following

```
curl --cookie "user=John" 127.0.0.1:7001/myApp/Ticket
```

I would expect it to move through states as they are defined in the state machine, but it always returns the same lines

> user: John
>
> current state: null
>
> new state: NEW

The ticket machine is quite simple

```
public class TicketMachine {    

    public static String getNextState(Object currentState){

        if(currentState == null)
            return "NEW";

        switch(currentState.toString()){        
        case "NEW":
            return "PAYMENT";
        case "PAYMENT":
            return "COMPLETED";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using --cookie-jar option in your curl and examining the response from server might be a good idea.

Comment: So how are you ensure that `Cookie user = receivedCookies[0];` is the cookie you are looking for, it would be server `sessionid` or anything else, also take care about comparing string with `==`, use `equals()` instead.

Comment: @user2511414 It is just a proof of point servlet so I don't really need to ensure it.

Comment: @Nishan I will try it. Does it mean that you don't see anything wrong at the first sight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When session is created it adds to response cookies session parameters such as session id. Your command to cURL does not stores cookies from server. You have to store cookies as follows `curl --cookie oldcookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt http://www.example.com`.

Also read section about cookies at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html